# Apps Script: How to Email Google Sheet file to Email Specified in HTML Service Input?

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I am working to build in an HTML Service UI within my Google Sheets file that allows the user to key in the target recipient email address inside the pop-up dialog box within the HTML form.  My code is currently not working effectively as an email is not being generated upon run.

JS Code:

```
    function openDialog() {
      var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Email?');
    }

    function sendEmail() {
    var to = document.getElementbyID("emailInput");
      MailApp.sendEmail( {
        email: to,
        subject: "good morning",
     })
     }
```

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
</head>
 <body>
      <form id="emailForm">
      Send to Email Address:<br> <input type="email" id="emailInput" 
      name="email" size="40"/><br>
      <button onClick="sendEmail()">Send</button>
      </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a server-side function from the client directly. You need to use the `google.script.run` API to communicate between the two. Try the following:

```js
// Inside your Apps Script .gs code

// listen for an object sent from the HTML form
function sendEmail(formObj) {

  // Extract the email address submitted
  var to = formObj.email;

  // Send the email
  MailApp.sendEmail(to,"good morning", "The email body")
}
```

```html
...
<body>
  <form id="emailForm">
      <p>Send to Email Address:</p>
      <br> 
      <input type="email" id="emailInput" name="email" size="40"/> <!-- "name" becomes the key in formObject -->
      <br>
      <input type="button" value="Send Email" onclick="google.script.run.sendEmail(this.parentNode)" /> <!-- google.script.run allows you to call server-side functions -->
      </form>
</body>
...
```

Comment: Thanks, Brian!  Still not firing an email, though.  am I missing something additional?

Comment: You can do two things to debug: View > Execution transcript in the editor will show all steps in the execution. You should see a failure message. You could also add `Logger.log(formObj.email) inside the `sendEmail` function to make sure you're getting data from the client.

Comment: Thanks for your additional help.  Execution transcript shows the following error message:

Execution failed: TypeError: Cannot read property "email" from null.

Comment: Sorry, there were some syntax errors. Updated the `sendEmail` function and the HTML.

Comment: Now getting this error message:

Execution failed: TypeError: Cannot call property email in object [object Object]. It is not a function, it is "string". (line 8, file "Code") [0.001 seconds total runtime]

Comment: Did you remove the curly braces in the MailApp function?

Comment: They are now gone.