# Google App Script + Google Sheet + HTML modal dialog input form - Get values and build email

Tags: javascript, html, email, google-apps-script, onclick

Another Sheets question.

I have an image on my Google Sheet, which runs a script which brings up a modal dialog built on HMTL:

```
function HomePageFurtherHelp(){ 

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  //
  //Call the HTML file and set the width and height
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("Home Page - Further Help")
    .setWidth(1200)
    .setHeight(1400);
  //Display the dialog
  var dialog = ui.showModalDialog(html, " ");
}
```

My HTML modal dialog window holds a few fields for user input: it's basically a contact information form and there is a "send" button. I have added 'id' parameters to each of my input fields in HTML. The form is just a free to use version that I've added id's into.

My question is: how can I fetch the users' inputted data and then pass it to the send button and send out an email to a preset email address? I have added an 'onclick' parameter to my Send button, I assume I call a function for the email itself inside 'onclick' but I don't know how to build it.

```
<div class="w3-row w3-section">
  <div class="w3-col" style="width:50px"><i class="w3-xxlarge fa fa-user"></i></div>
    <div class="w3-rest">
      <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="first" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" id="userName">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="w3-row w3-section">
  <div class="w3-col" style="width:50px"><i class="w3-xxlarge fa fa-sitemap"></i></div>
    <div class="w3-rest">
      <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="last" type="text" placeholder="Department" id="departmentName">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="w3-row w3-section">
  <div class="w3-col" style="width:50px"><i class="w3-xxlarge fa fa-envelope-o"></i></div>
    <div class="w3-rest">
      <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" id="userEmail">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="w3-row w3-section">
  <div class="w3-col" style="width:50px"><i class="w3-xxlarge fa fa-film"></i></div>
    <div class="w3-rest">
      <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Project?" id="projectName">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="w3-row w3-section">
  <div class="w3-col" style="width:50px"><i class="w3-xxlarge fa fa-pencil"></i></div>
    <div class="w3-rest">
      <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="message" type="text" placeholder="Message" id="userMessage">
    </div>
</div>

<button class="w3-button w3-block w3-section w3-blue w3-ripple w3-padding" onclick="contactSendEmail()">Send</button>
```

I did find this post: [Apps Script: How to Email Google Sheet file to Email Specified in HTML Service Input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48773187/apps-script-how-to-email-google-sheet-file-to-email-specified-in-html-service-i) but I am getting a bit confused breaking it apart, I am stuck on 'formObj' and using it.

Helping me understand it would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out using formObj, and calling my name parameters as keys - this was the bit I was missing.

This can be closed etc.